# Xcode 'No such module GoogleSignIn'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-signin, podfile

I don't know why I keep getting this error so frequently, is there a way to stop it? What's causing this? I always get to solve it by following this steps though:

1. Clean build folder and close Xcode.
2. Run `pod deintegrate` in terminal inside my project folder.
3. Run `pod install`.
4. Re open project and build.

I know it's not a big deal, but after getting this error 10 times already and my project being every time bigger in size, it's really time consuming and annoying. Because when I open my project again and build it, it takes a couple of minutes.

I would very much appreciate if someone comes up with a final solution to this, since the only thing I've found till date was to follow those steps, but as you can see it only fixes it for a limited time, not forever.

I'm wondering if it could be a problem inside my `Podfile`.

My Podfile:

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Insight' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Insight
  
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  
  pod 'HideKeyboardWhenTappedAround', '~> 1.0.0'
  
end

post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
  end
 end
end
```